# Changing owner of all folder except one folder

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

I want to change ownership of all of my folders, so I use this command:

```
chown -R root: *
```

Now I want to say change all folders except `./test` folder.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `extglob` option and then exclude the desired folder:

```
shopt -s extglob
chown -R root: !(test)
```

Comment: Thanks, can I use this command for all operations too? like `chmod`, `cp`, `mv` and ... ?

Comment: @MajAfy Yes, you can use it for other operations too.  But I hope that you've _understand_ the command.  Try saying `ls !(test)` to see what it does.

Comment: Thanks again, I run `shopt -s extglob` and there is no any output, then run `ls !(index.html)` this command will show all files in all directories !

Comment: @MajAfy Yes, that is the expected behavior.  `ls !(index.html)` would be equivalent to saying `ls *` __excluding__ `ls index.html`.

Comment: @MajAfy No, you can specify files too.